Error install helm opentelemetry collector on kubernetes error reading processors configuration for "k8sattributes": 3 error(s) decoding
I got an error while installing opentelemetry collector on kubernetes as daemonset

Kubernetes version: 1.23.11
Opentelemetry collector contrib version: 0.50.0
Helm : https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/opentelemetry-helm/opentelemetry-collector/0.50.0

error detail:
2024/10/15 08:11:53 proto: duplicate proto type registered: jaeger.api_v2.PostSpansRequest
2024/10/15 08:11:53 proto: duplicate proto type registered: jaeger.api_v2.PostSpansResponse
Error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: error reading processors configuration for "k8sattributes": 3 error(s) decoding:

* 'pod_association[0]' has invalid keys: sources
* 'pod_association[1]' has invalid keys: sources
* 'pod_association[2]' has invalid keys: sources
2024/10/15 08:11:53 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: error reading processors configuration for "k8sattributes": 3 error(s) decoding:

* 'pod_association[0]' has invalid keys: sources
* 'pod_association[1]' has invalid keys: sources
* 'pod_association[2]' has invalid keys: sources

piece of config:
config:  
  processors:
    batch:
      send_batch_size: 3
      timeout: 5s
    k8sattributes:
      extract:
        metadata:
        - k8s.namespace.name
        - k8s.deployment.name
        - k8s.statefulset.name
        - k8s.daemonset.name
        - k8s.cronjob.name
        - k8s.job.name
        - k8s.node.name
        - k8s.pod.name
        - k8s.pod.uid
        - k8s.pod.start_time
      filter:
        node_from_env_var: K8S_NODE_NAME
      passthrough: false
      pod_association:
      - sources:
        - from: resource_attribute
          name: k8s.pod.ip
      - sources:
        - from: resource_attribute
          name: k8s.pod.uid
      - sources:
        - from: connection
    memory_limiter:
      check_interval: 5s
      limit_percentage: 80
      spike_limit_percentage: 25

image:
  # If you want to use the core image `otel/opentelemetry-collector`, you also need to change `command.name` value to `otelcol`.
  repository: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: "0.50.0"
  # When digest is set to a non-empty value, images will be pulled by digest (regardless of tag value).
  digest: ""

command:
  name: otelcol-contrib
  extraArgs: []


The configuration for pod_association is slightly different in version v0.50.0, which is a really old version from April 2022. Try this:
      pod_association:
        - from: resource_attribute
          name: k8s.pod.ip
        - from: resource_attribute
          name: k8s.pod.uid
        - from: connection

On a separate note, version v0.50.0 has been long unsupported and likely contains bugs and security vulnerabilities. You should upgrade to the latest version of the chart and the collector.
